# Still Reachable allocated memory using valgrind

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, memcheck

I'm getting ready for an object oriented class starting in a few weeks, but I'm having trouble with the concept of deallocating memory. RIght now I'm just allocating memory to the first node of the stack, and then trying to deallocate it. If anyone could help me find what I am doing wrong with my destructor, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

The output I am getting from valgrind memcheck is:

```
==13653== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==13653==    at 0x4847DA4: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:328)
==13653==    by 0x10A2B: Stack::AddNode(int) (Stack.C:25)
==13653==    by 0x10923: main (Main.C:5)
==13653==
==13653== LEAK SUMMARY:
==13653==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13653==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13653==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13653==    still reachable: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==13653==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

***Code:***

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Stack {
  private:

    struct node{
      int data;
      node * prev;
    };

    node * stackptr;

  public:

   Stack() {
     stackptr = nullptr;
   }

   ~Stack() {
      cout << "Calling destructor" << endl;
      node * p1 = stackptr;
      node * delptr = nullptr;

      while(p1 != nullptr) {
        delptr = p1;
        p1 = p1->prev;
        delptr->prev = nullptr;
        cout << "Deleteing " << delptr->data << " from the stack" << endl;
        delete delptr;
      }
   }

   void AddNode(int data) {
      node * n = new node;
      n->data = data;

      if(stackptr == nullptr) {
        stackptr = n;
        stackptr->prev = nullptr;
      }
      else {
         n->prev = stackptr;
         stackptr = n;
      }
   }
};

int main() {
  Stack s;
  s.AddNode(1);
  s.AddNode(2);
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I have finished my AddNode class. I am still having a similar issue, but with two memory leaks now (The two calls to AddNode in main).

EDIT: Using C++ version 6.3.0 and valgrind version 3.13.0

Comment: (in general) Don't do manual memory management in modern C++. It's no longer the 90's - we have better ways. Research containers and smart pointers (and make sure you are using a up-to-date version of C++ like C++17 (or *at least* C++14)). Ohh and `using namespace std;` is going to bite you eventually - just ditch that bad habit now.

Comment: In `Stack::AddNode(int data)` what happens to `n` if `stackptr` is not null?

Comment: `Stack::Stack() {
  stackptr = nullptr;
}` at least use the constructors initialization list (or in-class initialization) - the constructor body is a last resort that comes with performance implications (object first default constructed, then assigned to, rather than just initialized once). Doesn't matter much for a simple pointer, but for complex objects it can be a killer and may not even be *possible* (and it's just a bad habit in general, with no up sides).

Comment: @Jesper Juhl I won't be able to use smart pointers in my class, so I figured it would be best to practice using them the way I am. I agree that smart pointers are much better to use though. Thank you for the info! I will have to look more into constructor initialization lists.

Comment: @user4581301 and drescherjm, as of right now, nothing happens. I'm only adding one thing to the stack to test it, and then trying to deallocate it. After I figure that out I will add more to AddNode.

Comment: The reason I asked is this is a memory leak. `n` is not added to the stack and is leaked if `stackptr  != nullptr`.

Comment: In that case I don't see a problem. Can we trouble you for a [mcve] so we can recreate exactly what you are doing?  Off topic: Here's what I wrote to make sure your destructor was  sane: https://ideone.com/KQyTd1 . You may find the `AddNode` method useful.

Comment: @user4581301 I have updated my original post with my minimal, complete example. I did my AddNode function a bit different than you did, but it looks like it is doing the same thing. Thank you for your help by the way.

Comment: Not a problem.  I'm not able to reproduce with or without valgrind. The leaks you have are tagged as still reachable. Could be that they are simply not being freed before the report is being generated. Make sure the program output announcing the deletes is before the valgrind output announcing the leaks, not after.

Comment: Because I forgot that you are making a stack, my addnode routine wouldn't be that useful to you. I wrote it to add nodes to the end. Since all you want to do is push and pop from the same spot, you might as well make it the beginning and you can't write it much better than what you've got unless you add a constructor to `node`.

Comment: @user4581301 I found out what it was! It's kind of odd, but when I removed "#include <iostream>" and all "cout" statements, I had no more still reachable memory. It must be something with including the library.

Comment: Interesting. If you can dig up the version of the compiler you are using and add it to the question someone might see it and go, "Oh. THAT bug." and let you in on a part of the mystery

Comment: @user4581301 That's a good idea! I have added the version of c++ and valgrind that I'm using.